# QDateTime widget looks bad under Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qdatetime

I have a project based on Qt 5.2.1 and it has QDateTime widget with calendar pop-up (calendarPopup option set on true). When i run my app under Ubuntu 13.10 (or looking in Qt Designer) QDateTime looks like:

[image: Ubuntu QDateTime]

and it's OK. But under Mac OS X 10.9.2 it looks like:

[image: MacOs QDateTime]

As you can see white area is higher than arrow and it looks pretty ugly. I've been searching information about this but found nothing. Can anyone help me to find workaround for this issue?

Note: it would be better to do it without creating custom widget. Am i able to set up styles or something exactly in QDateTime class?

Comment: I had some display error like this with a combobox when setting `frame`  to `false`. Maybe this is for whatever reason the default behaviour on mac?

Comment: @Bowdzone could be. But do people writing their Qt projects for Mac with so ugly control? However `frame` is `true` in my app and changing this has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by appending "border: 1px;" to QDateTime style sheets. Now it looks like:

[image: MacOS QDateTime with border]

Not perfect, but enough for me. Thanks @Bowdzone for giving me an idea!

Comment: A non-empty stylesheet simply drops the platform styling of the widget. You should report the original problem as a Qt bug, because it is a bug.

Comment: I didn't know about non-empty stylesheet drops styling, thanks a lot! I will report this bug.